# Can I use a StreamHandler for Logging in a Multiprocessing Environment in Python?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, stdout

Is it safe to use a single [StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html) in a multiprocessing environment?

More precisely, can it be problematic to have a just one `StreamHandler` that simply prints the logging statements of all processes to `stdout`? Like this, for example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import logging


def do_log(no):
    # 2nd EDIT, suppose we do also this,
    # which should not have any effect if there already exists a 
    # handler! But it probably has under Windows:
    format = '%(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
    # This creates a StreamHandler
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)

    # root logger logs Hello World
    logging.getLogger().info('Hello world {}'.format(no))


def main():
    format = '%(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
    # This creates a StreamHandler
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)

    n_cores = 4
    pool = mp.Pool(n_cores)
    # Log to stdout 100 times concurrently
    pool.map(do_log, range(100))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will print something like:

```
ForkPoolWorker-1 root INFO     Hello world 0
ForkPoolWorker-3 root INFO     Hello world 14
ForkPoolWorker-3 root INFO     Hello world 15
ForkPoolWorker-3 root INFO     Hello world 16
...
```

Is this a safe set up? If not what problems can arise? Anything more serious
than a garbled console output, i.e. program crash?

If it is safe, is it still safe when using `mp.Process` instead of `mp.Pool`?

**EDIT:** My question regards any OS, so if there are differences between Linux, OSX, or Windows, don't hesitate to tell me.

**2nd EDIT:** OK, so under Windows the handler disappears, what happens if we create a new StreamHandler for every process?

Comment: I have seen this work in a limited form. I'd have thought the worst that will happen is that some lines from different processes may become interleaved, and in other circumstances (not Python specifically) that tends to happen often if the system is under heavy load. Sorry this is only an anecdotal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not work at all on Windows, which may or may not be a problem for you. Because Windows doesn't have `fork`, the logger customization you do in the parent won't get inherited properly by the child.

On Linux/OS X, the only issue will be the messages from different processes getting garbled together. The `multiprocessing` documentation [mentions that when discussing logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#logging):

> Some support for logging is available. Note, however, that the `logging`
>   package does not use process shared locks so it is possible (depending
>   on the handler type) for messages from different processes to get
>   mixed up.

`mp.Pool` is implemented using `mp.Process`, so they'll behave completely equivalently here.

**Edit:**

If you want something basically equivalent to this that will also work on Windows, you need to run the logging config in each child process, as well as in the parent:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import logging


def do_log(no):
    # root logger logs Hello World
    logging.getLogger().info('Hello world {}'.format(no))

def init_log():
    fmt = '%(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=fmt, level=logging.INFO)

def main():
    # This creates a StreamHandler
    init_log()
    n_cores = 4
    pool = mp.Pool(n_cores, initializer=init_log)
    # Log to stdout 100 times concurrently
    pool.map(do_log, range(100))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    logging.getLogger().info("hi")
```

This gives you something that will have the same issues that the original version has on Linux (log messages will get garbled).

Comment: Uh ok, so far so good. What happens if I create a new StreamHandler under windows for each process? (See Edit)

Comment: I did not mean to have so many Edits, but this question just popped into my mind and I don't want to ask another question. If Windows prevents inheriting the StreamHandler, what happens if we create a new StreamHanlder for every process as above?

Comment: @SmCaterpillar See my edit. You get something essentially equivalent to the original version on Linux. Every process will write to stdout, but with no serialization between processes, meaning you'll get garbled messages if processes are writing simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks! How likely is it that they get garbled? Only for large messages? Because small ones are flushed at once?

Comment: @SmCaterpillar On Windows, the example code has partially garbled output every time I run it. It never ends up garbled on Linux, though I'm not sure exactly why. I don't think its anything Python is doing, so you probably shouldn't rely on it.